# How can I stop Wordpress from formatting 3 whitespace into 1?

Tags: php, wordpress, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a problem with Wordpress formatting my whitespaces, even though I don't want it to.

I have a dropdown with a bunch of options, one of them being:

```
Fighter 1110   8,5 kW
```

The 3 spaces between `1110` and `8,5 kW` is very important for the API I'm sending it too, which was made by another company. The API creators insist that it should have 3 spaces for the API to work.

When I add

```
Fighter 1110   8,5 kW
```

in the code, I can see when I inspect the page, that it has 3 spaces. But when i use rgpost() to get the value of the select, to send it to the API, it only has 1 space. I've tried to add 3 `&nbsp;` instead of normal space, but then if I var_dump() the string, it returns 'String(24) "Fighter 1110   8,5 kW"', but the string is only 21 long. I've then come to the conclusion that  `&nbsp;` counts as 2 instead of 1, which then makes it 24 instead of 21. So my question is:

How can I keep the 3 spaces, without using   ?

Answer (score 2):

Start by checkin into your database if the value is stored with one or three spaces. Do this to understand if the problems happen when your **set** the value or otherwise when you **get**

Next you can do the following:

- Substitute the three spaces whit a pipe `Fighter 1110|8,5 kW`
- When you need to submit the value replace back the pipe with the three spaces

The pipe is only an example, use what you want in place of pipe